# R using the ellipsis ... in a call()

Tags: r

I am trying to write a custom `curve` function where the `...` would be passed to the function rather than the plot: I would like to be able to use say:

```
curve2(dnorm, mean=2, sd=3)
```

I run into a problem with handling the `...` in a `call` environment. Starting from a simplified prototype of `curve`:

```
minicurve <- function (expr, from = 0, to = 1, ...) 
{
sexpr <- substitute(expr)
expr <- call(as.character(sexpr), as.name("x")) 
  ll <- list(x = seq(from=from, to=to, length.out=100))
  names(ll) <- "x"
  y <- eval(expr, envir = ll, enclos = parent.frame())
  plot(x = ll$x, y = y, type="l")
}

# This gives the same behaviour as `curve`:
minicurve(dnorm)
```

Now I would like to pass the `...` into the `call` (instead of passing into `plot`). Usually, this is very easy, one just need to pass the `...` into the function. However, the `call` function behaves differently, and I am not sure how I should handle it. I can just use:

```
 dot1 <- substitute(...)
 expr <- call(as.character(sexpr), as.name(xname), dot1)
```

This will work, however it will pass only the first argument. I need hence to use someting like:

```
 dots <- substitute(list(...))
 expr <- call(as.character(sexpr), as.name(xname), dots)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
minicurve2 <- function (expr, from = 0, to = 1, ...) 
{
 sexpr <- substitute(expr)
 dots <- substitute(list(...))
 expr <- call(as.character(sexpr), as.name(xname), dots) 
 ll <- list(x = seq(from=from, to=to, length.out=100))
 names(ll) <- "x"
 y <- eval(expr, envir = ll, enclos = parent.frame())
 plot(x = ll$x, y = y, type="l")
}
```

So how do I pass a list of `...` into the `call` function? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the solution requires `do.call()` and the creation of a list of arguments from the formal arguments and those passed in via `...`

Comment: Good intuition, although I think at then end `as.call()` is easier to use in this context!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this

```
minicurve <- function (expr, from = 0, to = 1, ...) {
    sexpr <- substitute(expr)
    expr <- call(as.character(sexpr), as.name("x")) 
    ll <- list(x = seq(from=from, to=to, length.out=100))
    names(ll) <- "x"

    dots <- substitute(...())
    expr <- as.call(c(as.list(expr), dots))

    y <- eval(expr, envir = ll, enclos = parent.frame())
    plot(x = ll$x, y = y, type="l")
}
```

Here we capture the `...` as a list via the `substitute(...())` syntax. Then we convert the call to a list, append in the parameters, and turn it back into a call.

We test with

```
minicurve(dnorm, mean=2, sd=3)
```

[image: mean 2]

```
minicurve(dnorm, mean=.5, sd=5)
```

[image: mean .5]

Comment: Great!! This indeed does the trick, thanks!! I had come up with something similar at then end:   dots <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  arg <- c(list(expr, as.name("x")), dots)
  expr <- as.call(arg) much as you suggest, thanks!!